# Parsing Balance Transfer Data

Tags: polkadot, balances, sidecar, substrate-api-sidecar

I'm writing a client in Go that needs to scan balance transfers in Substrate chains - initially focused on Polkadot.

My current objective is to determine all balance transfers in a given block, and to record the sender & destination IDs along with the value transferred.

To simplify decoding & storage access I'm using Sidecar.

### Balance Transfer Summary

If I understand correctly, balance transfers can be made by methods in the `balances` and `utility` pallets.

Balance transfer methods in `balances` pallet:

- `transfer`
- `transferAll`
- `transferKeepAlive`

Balance transfer methods in `utilities` pallet:

- `batch`
- `batchAll`

### Data Required

The data I need is the destination ID, sender ID and the value transferred.

In all cases, I am getting the sender ID directly from the Extrinsic signature.

For "standard" balance transfers that use `balances.transfer`, this data is present in the Extrinsic. Westend example [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fwestend-rpc.polkadot.io#/explorer/query/13690231)

This is not the case for `balances.TransferAll` - the Extrinsic does not directly hold data for `value` of the transfer - this must be obtained from the `balances.Transfer` event for that Extrinsic. Polkadot example [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/explorer/query/13282388)

For batched transactions under the `utilities` pallet, data for destination ID and value is obtained by looping over the `Extrinsic.Arg.Calls` and inspecting the `Args` of any balance transfer methods.

### Current Approach

My app scans for Extrinsics that relate to balance transfers.

In the case of a `utilities.batch` or `utilities.batchAll`:

- Get sender ID from Extrinsic
- Loop over the Extrinsic Calls
- Skip Calls whose methods do not relate to balance transfer (`balances` pallet, `transfer`, `transferAll`, `transferKeepAlive` methods)
- Get destination ID and Value for balance transfer events from the call Args

In the case of `balances.transfer`, `balances.transferAll` or `balances.transferKeepAlive` Extrinsics:

- Get sender ID from Extrinsic
- Get destination ID from Extrinsic
- Loop over Extrinsic Events
- Skip those that are not: `balances.Transfer`, `balances.TransferAll`, `balances.TransferKeepAlive`
- Get value from the `data` field of the Event

The `data` field of a balance transfer event as provided by Sidecar is an array of unlabeled strings. For example:

```json
{
    "method": {
        "pallet": "balances",
        "method": "Transfer"
    },
    "data": [
        "1qnJN7FViy3HZaxZK9tGAA71zxHSBeUweirKqCaox4t8GT7",
        "15uph1CrsXQgZYKFaumLC7wZEgC6gEnB2fZBpcDejt4xaEGd",
        "999000000000"
    ]
},

curl http://path-to-polkadot-mainnet-node-with-sidecar:8080/blocks/11555568 | jq '.extrinsics[3].events[3]'
```

### Question

1. Is my understanding of balance transfers correct?
2. Am I missing any potential balance transfer events?

Most importantly, can I rely on the third element in a balances transfer array provided by sidecar (as shown above) representing value?

It seems odd that this is not a named field, and it feels hacky accessing this data by means of an array index.

Thanks!